# How to handle/surpress Java ElasticSearch ConnectTransportException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently setting up a small project using elastic search in Java, and I am trying to figure out how to gracefully handle the 'ConnectTransportException' when my ElasticSearchCluster is down.

```
private TransportClient buildClient() {
    TransportClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {               
        logger.error("Unknown host {}: {}", "localhost", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return client;
}
```

This code works fine. When my ElasticSearch cluster isn't running I want to be able to know if the client was not able to connect to it and log an appropriate message and then handle it appropriately.

Currently when the client can't connect to the cluster I get this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:370) ~[transport-netty4-client-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:495) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNode(TcpTransport.java:460) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:314) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:408) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:354) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:195) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:322) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at elk.aggregator.ElasticClient.buildClient(ElasticClient.java:72) [classes/:?]
    at elk.aggregator.ElasticClient.<init>(ElasticClient.java:62) [classes/:?]
    at elk.aggregator.ElasticClient.getInstance(ElasticClient.java:55) [classes/:?]
    at elk.aggregator.App.main(App.java:9) [classes/:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:630) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:527) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:481) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441) ~[netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
```

I want to be able to handle this gracefully by catching the error, but simply adding another catch block catching ConnectTransportException does not work.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the code and handling for getting host and creating transport client then it will be more clear about the exception as below:

```
private boolean checkHostAvailability(String host, int port){
bool success = true;
try {
  (new Socket(host, port)).close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  success = false;
 logger.error("Unknown host {}: {}", host, e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
  success = false;
 logger.error("Service not running host {}: {}, {}", host, port, e.getMessage());
}

retrun success;
}

private TransportClient buildClient() {
String host = "localhost";
int port = 9300;
if(checkHostAvailability(host,port){

    TransportClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), port));
    } catch(Exception ex) {               

    }
    return client;
}

}
```